# Difference between date and time in a date time picker Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have two date time pickers in Jquery.

I need to show the difference on clicking the `show` button in the textbox with id `result`.

If

Time1 = **04/30/2014 10:27 am**

Time2 = **05/01/2014 10:26 am**

It should calculate its difference and show the result like `X days Y Hrs Z minutes`

In addition I want the date to be in `dd/mm/yy`. Right now it is `mm/dd/yy`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mh9EE/1/)

Comment: Can you use a library?

Comment: @DavidTansey If there is no way other than using a library, then it is fine. Otherwise I prefer doing this without a library.

Comment: You should probably look at Moment.js -- if you don't like the library concept you could just mimic the parts of the code that do what you need. ;)  It'll definitely show you the way.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/5fejH/)</kbd>

```
var time1 = $('#basic_example_1'), //cache selectors
    time2 = $('#basic_example_2'),
    result = $("#result");
$("#show").click(function () {
    var d1 = new Date(time1.val()), //convert to date object
        d2 = new Date(time2.val()), //convert to date object
        msec = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime(), //get difference in milliseconds
        hh = Math.floor(msec / 1000 / 60 / 60), //get hours
        dd = Math.floor(hh / 24); //calculate days
    msec -= hh * 1000 * 60 * 60; //remove hours from msec
    hh -= dd * 24; //remove days from hours
    var mm = Math.floor(msec / 1000 / 60); //get minutes
    result.val(dd + ' days ' + hh + ' Hrs ' + mm + ' minutes');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var start = $('#basic_example_1').datepicker('getDate');
var end = $('#basic_example_2').datepicker('getDate');
var diff = new Date(end - start);
var days = Math.floor(diff/1000/60/60/24);
var hours = Math.floor((diff % ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / 1000 / 60 / 60);
var minutes = Math.floor((diff % ( 1000 * 60 * 60)) / 1000 / 60);
$("#result").val(days+' Day(s) '+hours+' Hour(s) '+minutes+' Minute(s)');
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mh9EE/2/)